# Limitation of Developing Cross-Plaform Xamarin Projects only on VS2012 Professional

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, xamarin-studio

According to this [page](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/visual_studio_with_xamarin/cross_platform_visual_studio_project_setup_walkthrough/); in order to develop Cross-Platform Xamarin Projects (Android Native, iOS Native, Windows Phone Native - not Xamarin.Forms) you need Visual Studio 2012 Professional only. But maybe this page is old?

- Can you use Visual Studio 2013 Express
- Can you use Visual Studio 2012 Express?
- Can you use Xamarin Studio (to develop Cross Platform projects - Android Native, iOS Native, not Windows Phone)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio Express editions do not support plug-ins, which are required by Xamarin.  You need 2012 Pro (or better).

You can use Xamarin Studio on a **Mac** to build Android and iOS Apps.

You can use Xamarin Studio on a **PC** to build Android apps (not iOS).

You can use Visual Studio (with a Xamarin Business License) on a **PC** to build Android and iOS Apps.  But building iOS Apps on a PC requires you to have a Mac to act as a build host.